# django_plotly_dash: error exporting to pdf with html2pdf.js

Tags: javascript, django, plotly-dash, html2pdf

I am trying to export a django_plotly_dash dashboard to pdf and can't quite get it. I am stuck with the following error in console when clicking on the button to trigger the export:

```
ReferenceError: html2pdf is not defined
    at Object.nClicksToPDF [as n_clicks]
```

which is telling me that html2pdf cannot be found. I have tried importing in assets folder as well as cdn directly in the app layout but nothing seems to do the trick and I am out of things to try:

here is how I import it in the app:

```
 html.Script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"),
```

here is my callback where it is called:

```
app.clientside_callback(
    """
function nClicksToPDF(n_clicks){
  if(n_clicks > 0){
    document.querySelector('.chkremove').style.display = 'none';
    const opt = {
      margin: 2,
      filename: 'myfile.pdf',
      image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas: { scale: 1},
      jsPDF: { unit: 'cm', format: 'a2', orientation: 'p' },
      pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all'] }
    };
    console.log('ok')

    html2pdf().from(document.getElementById("print")).set(opt).save();
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.querySelector('.chkremove').style.display = 'block';
    }, 2000);
  }
}
    """,
    Output('js','n_clicks'),
    Input('js','n_clicks')
)
```

Don't know what else to do, any help would be highly welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `html.Script` component, which does not work as one might expect : in short, the `<script>` tag is created, but never executed.

It is part of a larger issue : [Several components have limited or no functionality in current browsers](https://github.com/plotly/dash-html-components/issues/129) :

> [...] browsers don't execute `<script>`s inserted in the way react does it (via innerHTML). Including `html.Script` in the documentation only leads folks
> down dead ends. Either it should use a different insertion mechanism,
> or it should have a bright big warning in the docs, or it should be
> removed entirely.

The alternative is to add html2pdf as an external script, ie :

```py
scripts = [{
  'src': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js'
}]

app = DjangoDash(__name__, external_scripts=scripts)
```